# Neo4j find maximum size in bytes for database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I found the following information on how to calculate the size of neo4j database: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/#_disk_storage

> An example disk space calculation is:
>
> 10,000    Nodes x 14B = 140kB 1,000,000 Rels  x 33B = 31.5MB 2,010,000
>   Props x 41B = 78.6MB
>
> Total  is 110.2MB

Is there a query that could simply fetch this information for me?

For the node count the query is simple:

```
match (n) return count(n);
```

for the rel count the query would be as follows:

```
match (n)-[r]-() return count(r);
```

How do I get the count of all properties of all nodes and relations combined though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your main question, use the [`keys`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-keys) function to get a list of property names and summarize their length:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH SUM(SIZE(KEYS(n))) AS countOfNodeProps, 
     COUNT(n) AS countOfNodes
MATCH ()-[r]->()
WITH countOfNodeProps,
     countOfNodes,
     SUM(SIZE(KEYS(r))) AS countOfRelProps,
     COUNT(r) AS countOfRels
RETURN countOfNodeProps,
       countOfRelProps,
       (countOfNodeProps + countOfRelProps) as countOfProps,
       countOfNodes,
       countOfRels
```

But it's easier to use the [`apoc.monitor.store`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_monitoring) function to get the exact information about the storage:

```
CALL apoc.monitor.store() YIELD 
    logSize, 
    stringStoreSize, 
    arrayStoreSize, 
    relStoreSize, 
    propStoreSize, 
    totalStoreSize, 
    nodeStoreSize
RETURN *
```

Comment: what are the results returned by logSize etc.? Size in bits or bytes?